# How to set up online directory that two servers can access?

Tags: php, heroku, ftp, file-transfer

I have a very weird, but specific situation. I use XAMPP localhost on my mac, call it server1, and heroku running a php app, call it server2. I need to move a txt file from server1 to server2 (at regular intervals as the txt constantly updates). I cannot use PHP's ftp as heroku doesn't like that. I have no idea how to do this.

I have come up with a plan to somehow get the txt from server1 to an online 'directory' that the app on server2 can access, but I have no idea how to do this, or if this is even possible? Is there a better way to transfer the file? Should I not be using heroku for this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is great for running PHP apps, but it has an ephemeral filesystem. It's not build to upload files and store them on the "server".
(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)

If you deploy a new version of your app to Heroku, the uploaded file will be removed. If you don't mind uploading the file again, simply push it to your PHP app running on Heroku using a POST request.

If you want to save it more reliable, think about using a storage service like AWS S3.